# Probability measure, that is not tight

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was thinking about tightness of probability measures and wondered what a non-tight probability measure might look like. I couldn't really think of one. Anyone know a good example?

Comment: Maybe reading this would help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures#A_collection_of_point_masses

Comment: Mhhh... yes I knew those things. The problem I'm having is that I am trying to find a single probability measure that isn't tight. Maybe I should elaborate:

Comment: I was trying to find a probability measure that is not tight. Of course for this to be feasible, I first need to find a space, on which it is defined, that is not Polish. I thought of $\mathbb{N}$ endowed with the discrete topology, but I couldn't construct one.

Comment: What about the examples there, then? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_regular_measure

Comment: That was helpful and interesting. Thanks al lot.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

$\{F_n(x)=1_{[n,\infty)}(x),n\ge 1\}$ is a sequence of non-tight probability distribution functions.